# Docpad Scss doesn't work

Tags: sass, docpad

I'm trying to get docpad working with scss on a windows 7 system.

As far as I know i've got sass installed and working cause it starts running from the command line. The path in the environment vars is correct.

docpad is working cause I get compiled code in the out folder.

but when I add a css.scss file I get an error

Error: SCSS does not appear to be available on your system

I tried to add a plugin config:

plugins:
   sass:
      scssPath: "/Ruby139/bin"

but that gives another error

Does anyone have an idea what to try now?

Comment: And there you go, found the answer:
set the correct path for the plugin:
 plugins:
  sass:
   sassPath: 's:/Ruby193/bin/sass.bat'
   scssPath: 's:/Ruby193/bin/scss.bat'

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is set the correct path to the sass batch files in the ruby folder:

```
plugins:
    sass:
        sassPath: 's:/Ruby193/bin/sass.bat'
        scssPath: 's:/Ruby193/bin/scss.bat'
```